# Exception while using exe in C#

Tags: java, c#, exe

I created an exe for a Java code and i am trying to use it in C# app. I am using it like this

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.FileName = "abc.exe";
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.Arguments = args; 

try
{
    // Start the process with the info we specified.
    // Call WaitForExit and then the using statement will close.
    using (Process exeProcess = Process.Start(startInfo))
    {
         exeProcess.WaitForExit();
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // Log error.
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Just after this i read the text file which the exe is supposed to create.

```
System.IO.StreamReader file =
           new System.IO.StreamReader(textFile);
```

But i am getting exception while reading the text file saying "File is being used by another process."

Now i am sure no other process is accessing this file except the exe. And i also invoked the WaitForExit() method. But still i am getting the exception. Does anyone know how to solve this?

EDIT:
I tested the code again by deleting the text file and running the code again.I got the exception FileNotFound.So it seems the code is trying to read the file even before the exe is finished writing it. How can i force reading the file to happen only after the file has been released by the exe?

Comment: In the Java code, did you close the file or stream?

Comment: It´s the *text file* is the most probable cause of the error; could you provide the code that create the text file?

Comment: Sounds like the file still hasn't been released.  As an experiment, put `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.Sleep(1000);` after you close the using statement.  If the exception is no longer being thrown, then you'll know.  If that does get rid of it, then you'll need to ensure that the file is completely released to the OS in your Java EXE.  How to do that should be put into SO as a separate question.

Comment: @KemalKefeli yes i did close the PrintWriter in Java code

Comment: @Micky plz check the edit

Answer (score -1):

You are blocking your application with WaitForExit call, so preventing Windows from processing UI events. I propose to move your code to another methods like this

Edit: So you may do not have another code after runnning abc or ebc might be too fast.

```
class Program
{
    private static bool eventHandled;
    private static int elapsedTime;


    static void Main(string[] inputArgs)
    {
        string args = string.Empty;

        try
        {
            Process exeProcess = new Process();
            exeProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
            exeProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            exeProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "abc.exe";
            exeProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            exeProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = args;
            exeProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            exeProcess.Exited +=  OnProcessExited;
            exeProcess.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Log error.
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }

        // Wait for Exited event, but not more than 30 seconds.
        const int SLEEP_AMOUNT = 100;
        while (!eventHandled)
        {
            elapsedTime += SLEEP_AMOUNT;
            if (elapsedTime > 30000)
            {
                break;
            }
            Thread.Sleep(SLEEP_AMOUNT);
        }
    }

    private static void OnProcessExited(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        // do your work here   
        eventHandled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: i tested ur code. Control never comes to the func OnProcessExited.

Comment: As it do wotk in async, you should have another code waiting for the results. Try my edit.

Comment: Not sure how this answer addresses the _"file is being used..."_ exception? Also your "workaround" for UI blocking isn't so because you loop around performing `Thread.Sleep()` which would block the UI.  OP didn't mention a UI anyway